# Struggling to display a modelForm in admin panel

Tags: python, django

Im trying add custom ModelForm to Django admin panel, however I am getting this error. `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Unknown field(s) (tron, rchain, etc..)`
I want to have a form in admin-panel when you click add to 'Currencies' there will be a choice of currencies and you can select one.

I have been tweaking it for a while and can not come up with a solution.
Basically, i believe I need to create a model instances 'on the go' whenever I select a currency in the admin panel.But how do I achieve it ?

My code below

```
#modelForm.py
class Currencies_Form(ModelForm):
#tuplez = [(i,) for i in Coins.arr]
cryptoId = forms.ChoiceField(choices=Coins.arr, initial=' ', widget=forms.Select())
class Meta:
    model = Currencies
    fields = Coins.arr
```

models.py

```
class Currencies(models.Model):
    cryptoId = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    cryptoPrice = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

My file with an api call and data - CoinAPI.py

```
class Coins:


def __init__(self):
    self.arr = []
    self.hashTable = {}

    params = 100
    data = requests.get('https://api.coinmarketcap.com/v1/ticker/?limit={}'.format(params)).json()
    for objects in data:
        for k in objects.keys():
            if k == 'id':
                self.arr += objects[k].split()
                self.hashTable.update({objects[k]:objects['price_usd']})
Coins = Coins()
```

and my admin.py

```
class whatever(admin.ModelAdmin):
form = Currencies_Form


admin.site.register(Currencies,whatever)
```

Please don't mind the naming, clearly not PEP-8 standard, it's just for my local testing yet.
To clarify what I want I'll post a screenshots

[image]

on the add button I want a list of available currencies from the Coins.arr(array of currency names)

[image]

almsot like this but as a list to select 1 from.
I realise this post isn't great, but I really have no idea how else to explain this.

Comment: Please fix your code indentation, and clarify your question - as far as I'm concerned I just can't understand what you're trying to do.

Comment: @brunodesthuilliers I've updated my post, hopefully it clarifies what I want

Comment: "fields = Coins.arr" => re-read the doc about what a ModelForm's Meta.fields attribute is used for. Also re-read the doc about what a ChoiceField's choices attributes expect. And while we're at it, learn to properly use Python's dicts, lists and classes - your "Coin" class code is a complete WTF.

Answer (score 0):

You could create a Currency model which you would query to add/remove currencies from coinmarketcap.com. Then you could relate the Currency model to the Currencies model.

If it's not required that you add to the Currencies model from the admin panel you could just create a view which would query coinmarketcap.com and then make a custom form which would add the selected currency to the Currencies model.